# Requirements for linear mixed effects models

Tags: mixed-model

I would like to calculate a linear mixed model and check the requirements beforehand. Unfortunately, I can't find any exact information about what all has to apply. I have a single predictor that predicts a criterion. It is about evaluations of quality of different objects. An expert has evaluated the quality. This expert rating is now supposed to predict the ratings of lay people. For this I let 50 laypeople rate the different objects (not everyone had all but a random selection). The individual persons as well as the objects are both implemented as random effects in the model.

Which conditions do I have to check in the data now to calculate a mixed model?

I would be grateful for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the usual conditions such as the model matrices, for both fixed and random effects, being of full rank (and the number of random effects being fewer than the number of observations), and perhaps an assessment for possible non-linearity by plotting the data, there is nothing really to check in the data itself.

For random intercepts it is nice to have a more than 20 groups/subjects/clusters. It is still possible to fit a model with fewer, but this is hard to justify once the number of groups falls below around 6, since the software will estimate a variance based on however many groups there are, as the number of observations of a normally distributed variable and try to estimate a variance for it.

Comment: Although, in a Bayesian context with at least weakly informative priors, fitting varying intercepts models with a small number of groups is definitely possible.